# How to use logistic regression on time series data?

Tags: regression, time-series, logistic, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

My question is more theoretical and hope someone can help me. I have socio-demographic data for 2007, 2010, 2011 and 2020 years from the statistical office. All of variables are categorical, while the Dependent variable is binary. I want to explain dependence and think about using logistic regression. However I have some doubts, should I treat this data as time series or I can just use it as usual?

Comment: Assume independence and run your model then check the residuals if they are correlated (so the independence assumption is falsified) then you might think about incorporating the time's effect as well.

Comment: @AminShn That's good advice.  But in the present case, how should one compute residuals and how exactly can they be checked for correlation?  Remember, this is a logistic  regression, not least squares; and each of the time series is short and irregularly spaced.  In light of these challenges, a generalized linear mixed model comes to mind as potentially being more effective and easier to carry out.

Comment: @whuber he can check the assumption of residuals being independent from time by conducting a chi-squared test to see if the proportion of misclassifications significantly varies among years. If yes then more complicated approaches like GLMM that you suggested could be performed but even that treats years as categorical and ignores the ordering (if you mean random intercept/slope based on year), so adding a simple coefficient for year could be an easier solution and maybe more justified?

Comment: @Amin You lost me at the outset, because logistic regression does not classify anything.  Although it can be used for classification, that requires introducing a threshold for comparing the predicted log odds--and that threshold needn't be, and often is not, $0.$

Comment: @whuber the threshold could be set to p = 0.5 above which he can predict 1 and 0 otherwise and I don't see how that could be not valid JUST for checking the independence assumption otherwise I know he is most probably interested in estimating the effects of his socio-demographic variables and not classification of the response variable per se.

Comment: @AminShn I suppose you could do that as part of a principled exploration of a *range* of thresholds.  Testing with just one such (arbitrary) threshold won't be very powerful.  I think the points you are making in these comments are good, but you might be underestimating the complexity and difficulty of carrying out your proposed approach in an effective manner.  That's why it would be nice to know the details.